# Windows command prompt showing incorrect time since epoch

Tags: windows, powershell, datetime, command-prompt, unix-timestamp

I am trying to monitor my app launch time on a Windows machine using command prompt. This is how I launch my electron app

```
powershell -command "(New-TimeSpan -Start (Get-Date "01/01/1970") -End (Get-Date)).TotalSeconds" & electron .
```

The time returned by command prompt looks hugely off. The following are values returned

- command prompt - 1706093824 (sec)
- electron app - 1706074025844 (msec)

In electron I am printing using

```
const now = Date.now(); // Unix timestamp in milliseconds
console.log( now );
```

Why is command prompt returning incorrect time? Can someone please suggest what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This is a 5.5 hour difference. One of your calls is timezone aware (likely using system time), while the other is in most likely in UTC, hence the difference. Figure out which one is which and account for the difference (probably easiest to change your local one to be UTC, usually just with a single argument), and you should see them line up

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Stitt the time difference was due to local time zone. Subtracting it gave correct results.

Answer (score 0):

`Get-Date` returns the local time, therefore `Get-Date "01/01/1970"` is the 01/01/1970 in your timezone, not the Unix Epoch timezone.

Your method to get Unix time is completely wrong. In PowerShell Core just use this

```
Get-Date -UFormat %s
```

And in older PowerShell due to a bug in `-UFormat %s` then you'll need to use either of the below

```
(Get-Date).ToUniversalTime() | Get-Date -UFormat %s
Get-Date -date (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime() -UFormat %s
```

It'll return the correct Unix Time from the exact Unix Epoch in UTC

> `%s`: Seconds elapsed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 (UTC)
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-7.3